# Cargar archivos a una tabla por medio de un input

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla donde cargo datos desde un *form modal*, después esos datos de la tabla lo envío a una *sheet* de Google, pero lo que no puedo resolver es como lograr que mi `input type="file"` me lo muestre en la tabla.

Así tengo el HTML:

```
 <input class="for-control" type="file" id="formFileMultipleInput" multiple />
```

El JS:

```
let dataForm = new FormData($formModal) //Capturo el modal donde tengo el form
let $formFileMultipleInput = dataForm.values("formFileMultipleInput"); //le asigno para que capture los archivos que ingreso
```

El tema es que en la consola el archivo que captura `$formFileMultipleInput` es un *itinerator*, si uso `dataForm.get("formFileMultipleInput");` me da un *null*, ¿En qué estoy fallando?

Comment: Parece que necesitas ponerle un name a tu input <input class="for-control" type="file" id="formFileMultipleInput" name="formFileMultipleInput" multiple />

Comment: ¿Que formato de archivo quieres subir? y ¿Quieres que el contenido de tu archivo aparezca en la hoja de calculo de google?

Comment: @AlejoFlorez exacto, y que tambien aparescan en la tabla del html

Comment: @Csharls sige dando un itinerator con el name

Comment: una forma de acceder a los datos es crear un array a partir de los datos del form `Array.from(dataForm?.values())`